# After joomla version update, menu is not working

Tags: php, joomla, menu, content-management-system

Facing issue with Joomla menu, Menu link is not working, its always showing home page.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's going to be difficult for anyone to help you unless they have more information. Can you post a url?

Comment: Might be a .htaccess file issue.  Replace with default one and see if that affects.

Comment: Actually i am using *gantry 5*-> *Remnant theme* for one of the my joomla website,   I am unable to find the solution. When i am going to click any of the menu its opening only home page,

Comment: Here is the URL **https://www.pso.org.au/current/**

Comment: Issue resolved 
thank you